# efficient way to transform XML document into tabular dataset in SQL because cross apply xml query performs exponentially worse as xml grows

Tags: xml, azure, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have a big size XML document (50.000-100,000) that needs to be parsed on Azure SQL that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<covid-19 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://covid-19.iss.it/XMLSchema/0.1/">
    <pazienti>
        <paziente>
            <codiceRegionalePaziente>0123456789</codiceRegionalePaziente>
            <codiceFiscale/>
            <nome>nomeBulk01</nome>
            <cognome>cognomeBulk01</cognome>
            <dataNascita>1989-12-31</dataNascita>
            <sesso>F</sesso>
            <nazionalita>380</nazionalita>
            <domicilioIndirizzo/>
            <domicilioCap>00019</domicilioCap>
            <domicilioComune>058104</domicilioComune>
            <domicilioProvincia>RM</domicilioProvincia>
            <residenzaIndirizzo/>
            <residenzaCap/>
            <residenzaComune/>
            <residenzaProvincia/>
            <luogoEsposizione>cinema</luogoEsposizione>
            <luogoEsposizioneComune>058047</luogoEsposizioneComune>
            <operatoreSanitario>1</operatoreSanitario>
            <casoIsolato>9</casoIsolato>
            <casoCollegato/>
            <codiceTampone>kkk12345</codiceTampone>
            <dataPrelievo>2020-03-01</dataPrelievo>
            <codLaboratorioAnalisi>999</codLaboratorioAnalisi>
            <sequenzaGenoma>9</sequenzaGenoma>
            <sequenzaInviata>0</sequenzaInviata>
            <dataInizioSintomi>2020-03-01</dataInizioSintomi>
            <codRegione>99</codRegione>
            <patologieCroniche>9</patologieCroniche>
            <tumoriAttivi/>
            <diabeteMellito/>
            <malattieCardiovascolari/>
            <hiv/>
            <malattieRespiratorieCroniche/>
            <malattieRenali/>
            <altreMalattieMetaboliche/>
            <obesitaBmi30e40/>
            <obesitaBmiOltre40/>
            <malattieEpatiche/>
            <malattieCronicheNeurologiche/>
            <altrePatologie/>
            <altrePatologieDescrizione/>
            <note>test caricamento massivo da file xml</note>
            <collocazioni>
                <collocazione>
                    <dataCollocazione>2020-03-01</dataCollocazione>
                    <collocazioneTipo>Ospedale</collocazioneTipo>
                    <ospedaleNSIS>99999999</ospedaleNSIS>
                    <ospedaleReparto>Pneumologia</ospedaleReparto>
                </collocazione>
            </collocazioni>
            <statiClinici>
                <statoClinico>
                    <tipoStatoClinico>Asintomatico</tipoStatoClinico>
                    <dataStatoClinico>2020-03-01</dataStatoClinico>
                    <terapiaInCorso>0</terapiaInCorso>
                    <terapiaDescrizione/>
                    <intubato>0</intubato>
                </statoClinico>
                <statoClinico>
                    <tipoStatoClinico>Lieve</tipoStatoClinico>
                    <dataStatoClinico>2020-03-12</dataStatoClinico>
                    <terapiaInCorso>0</terapiaInCorso>
                    <terapiaDescrizione/>
                    <intubato>0</intubato>
                </statoClinico>
                <statoClinico>
                    <tipoStatoClinico>Critico</tipoStatoClinico>
                    <dataStatoClinico>2020-03-18</dataStatoClinico>
                    <terapiaInCorso>0</terapiaInCorso>
                    <terapiaDescrizione/>
                    <intubato>1</intubato>
                </statoClinico>
            </statiClinici>
        </paziente>
        <paziente>
            <codiceRegionalePaziente>AABB1234567890</codiceRegionalePaziente>
            <codiceFiscale>AAABBB00C11D222E</codiceFiscale>
            <nome>nomeBulk02</nome>
            <cognome>cognomeBulk02</cognome>
            <dataNascita>2000-01-31</dataNascita>
            <sesso>M</sesso>
            <nazionalita>380</nazionalita>
            <domicilioIndirizzo>Via del domicilio</domicilioIndirizzo>
            <domicilioCap>00100</domicilioCap>
            <domicilioComune>058091</domicilioComune>
            <domicilioProvincia>RM</domicilioProvincia>
            <residenzaIndirizzo/>
            <residenzaCap/>
            <residenzaComune/>
            <residenzaProvincia/>
            <luogoEsposizione>centro commerciale</luogoEsposizione>
            <luogoEsposizioneComune>058091</luogoEsposizioneComune>
            <operatoreSanitario>0</operatoreSanitario>
            <casoIsolato>1</casoIsolato>
            <casoCollegato/>
            <codiceTampone>00AABB-CC</codiceTampone>
            <dataPrelievo>2020-02-29</dataPrelievo>
            <codLaboratorioAnalisi>999</codLaboratorioAnalisi>
            <sequenzaGenoma>1</sequenzaGenoma>
            <sequenzaInviata>0</sequenzaInviata>
            <dataInizioSintomi>2020-02-29</dataInizioSintomi>
            <codRegione>99</codRegione>
            <patologieCroniche>1</patologieCroniche>
            <tumoriAttivi>0</tumoriAttivi>
            <diabeteMellito>0</diabeteMellito>
            <malattieCardiovascolari>1</malattieCardiovascolari>
            <hiv>0</hiv>
            <malattieRespiratorieCroniche>1</malattieRespiratorieCroniche>
            <malattieRenali>0</malattieRenali>
            <altreMalattieMetaboliche>0</altreMalattieMetaboliche>
            <obesitaBmi30e40>0</obesitaBmi30e40>
            <obesitaBmiOltre40>0</obesitaBmiOltre40>
            <malattieEpatiche>0</malattieEpatiche>
            <malattieCronicheNeurologiche>0</malattieCronicheNeurologiche>
            <altrePatologie>1</altrePatologie>
            <altrePatologieDescrizione>descrizione altra patologia cronica</altrePatologieDescrizione>
            <note>test caricamento massivo da file xml</note>
            <collocazioni>
                <collocazione>
                    <dataCollocazione>2020-03-01</dataCollocazione>
                    <collocazioneTipo>Domicilio</collocazioneTipo>
                    <ospedaleNSIS/>
                    <ospedaleReparto/>
                </collocazione>
                <collocazione>
                    <dataCollocazione>2020-03-05</dataCollocazione>
                    <collocazioneTipo>Ospedale</collocazioneTipo>
                    <ospedaleNSIS>99999999</ospedaleNSIS>
                    <ospedaleReparto>Malattie infettive e tropicali</ospedaleReparto>
                </collocazione>
            </collocazioni>
            <statiClinici>
                <statoClinico>
                    <tipoStatoClinico>Pauci-sintomatico</tipoStatoClinico>
                    <dataStatoClinico>2020-02-29</dataStatoClinico>
                    <terapiaInCorso>0</terapiaInCorso>
                    <terapiaDescrizione/>
                    <intubato>0</intubato>
                </statoClinico>
                <statoClinico>
                    <tipoStatoClinico>Severo</tipoStatoClinico>
                    <dataStatoClinico>2020-03-17</dataStatoClinico>
                    <terapiaInCorso>1</terapiaInCorso>
                    <terapiaDescrizione>descrizione  della terapia in corso</terapiaDescrizione>
                    <intubato>0</intubato>
                </statoClinico>
            </statiClinici>
        </paziente>
        <paziente>
            <codiceRegionalePaziente>9999999</codiceRegionalePaziente>
            <codiceFiscale/>
            <nome>nomeBulk03</nome>
            <cognome>cognomeBulk03</cognome>
            <dataNascita>2000-01-31</dataNascita>
            <sesso>M</sesso>
            <nazionalita>380</nazionalita>
            <domicilioIndirizzo>Via del domicilio</domicilioIndirizzo>
            <domicilioCap>00100</domicilioCap>
            <domicilioComune>058091</domicilioComune>
            <domicilioProvincia>RM</domicilioProvincia>
            <residenzaIndirizzo/>
            <residenzaCap/>
            <residenzaComune/>
            <residenzaProvincia/>
            <luogoEsposizione>centro commerciale</luogoEsposizione>
            <luogoEsposizioneComune>058091</luogoEsposizioneComune>
            <operatoreSanitario>0</operatoreSanitario>
            <casoIsolato>1</casoIsolato>
            <casoCollegato/>
            <codiceTampone>00AABB-CC</codiceTampone>
            <dataPrelievo>2020-02-29</dataPrelievo>
            <codLaboratorioAnalisi>999</codLaboratorioAnalisi>
            <sequenzaGenoma>1</sequenzaGenoma>
            <sequenzaInviata>0</sequenzaInviata>
            <dataInizioSintomi>2020-02-29</dataInizioSintomi>
            <codRegione>99</codRegione>
            <patologieCroniche>1</patologieCroniche>
            <tumoriAttivi>0</tumoriAttivi>
            <diabeteMellito>0</diabeteMellito>
            <malattieCardiovascolari>1</malattieCardiovascolari>
            <hiv>0</hiv>
            <malattieRespiratorieCroniche>1</malattieRespiratorieCroniche>
            <malattieRenali>0</malattieRenali>
            <altreMalattieMetaboliche>0</altreMalattieMetaboliche>
            <obesitaBmi30e40>0</obesitaBmi30e40>
            <obesitaBmiOltre40>0</obesitaBmiOltre40>
            <malattieEpatiche>0</malattieEpatiche>
            <malattieCronicheNeurologiche>0</malattieCronicheNeurologiche>
            <altrePatologie>1</altrePatologie>
            <altrePatologieDescrizione>descrizione altra patologia cronica</altrePatologieDescrizione>
            <note>test caricamento massivo da file xml</note>
            <collocazioni>
            </collocazioni>
            <statiClinici>
            </statiClinici>
        </paziente>
    </pazienti>
</covid-19>
```

I need to split it into 3 regular table type dataset (pazienti, collocazioni, statiClinici) and I use the following T-SQL code that works:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @StartTime datetime = getdate()
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    -- DROP temp tables
    if object_id('tempdb..#xmlPazienti') is not null DROP TABLE #xmlPazienti;
    if object_id('tempdb..#xmlCollocazioni') is not null DROP TABLE #xmlCollocazioni;
    if object_id('tempdb..#xmlStatiClinici') is not null DROP TABLE #xmlStatiClinici;

    -- pazienti --
    CREATE TABLE #xmlPazienti
    (
        [patientId] [int] NULL
        ,[codiceFiscale] [varchar](16) NULL
        ,[nome] [nvarchar](255) NULL
        ,[cognome] [nvarchar](255) NULL
        ,[dataNascita] [datetime] NULL
        ,[sesso] [char](1) NULL
        ,[nazionalita] [smallint] NULL
        ,[domicilioInd] [varchar](255) NULL
        ,[domicilioCap] [varchar](10) NULL
        ,[domicilioCom] [varchar](255) NULL
        ,[domicilioProv] [varchar](255) NULL
        ,[residenzaInd] [varchar](255) NULL
        ,[residenzaCap] [varchar](10) NULL
        ,[residenzaCom] [varchar](255) NULL
        ,[residenzaProv] [varchar](255) NULL
        ,[luogoEsp] [nvarchar](500) NULL
        ,[luogoEspCom] [varchar](255) NULL
        ,[operatoreSanitario] [tinyint] NULL
        ,[casoIsolato] [tinyint] NULL
        ,[casoCollegato] [varchar](500) NULL
        ,[CodiceTampone] [varchar](255) NULL
        ,[dataPrelievo] [date] NULL
        ,[LaboratorioAnalisiId] [smallint] NULL
        ,[sequenzaGenoma] [tinyint] NULL
        ,[sequenzaInviata] [tinyint] NULL
        ,[DataInizioSintomi] [date] NULL
        ,[codRegione] [smallint] NULL
        ,[PatologieCroniche] [tinyint] NULL
        ,[TumoriAttivi] [tinyint] NULL
        ,[DiabeteMellito] [tinyint] NULL
        ,[MalattieCardiovascolari] [tinyint] NULL
        ,[HIV] [tinyint] NULL
        ,[MalattieRespiratorieCroniche] [tinyint] NULL
        ,[MalattieRenali] [tinyint] NULL
        ,[AltreMalattieMetaboliche] [tinyint] NULL
        ,[ObesitàBMI30e40] [tinyint] NULL
        ,[ObesitàBMIoltre40] [tinyint] NULL
        ,[MalattieEpatiche] [tinyint] NULL
        ,[MalattieCronicheNeurologiche] [tinyint] NULL
        ,[AltrePatologie] [tinyint] NULL
        ,[AltrePatologieDescrizione] [nvarchar](500) NULL
        ,[Note] [nvarchar](4000) NULL
        ,[patientID_reg] [nvarchar](50) NULL
        ,[flagBaseline] [int] NULL
    )
    -- pazienti --

    -- collocazioni --
    CREATE TABLE #xmlCollocazioni
    (
    dataRicovero date NULL
    ,collocazioneId int NULL
    ,idOspedale nvarchar(255) NULL
    ,CodReparto int NULL
    ,patientID int NULL
    ,patientID_reg nvarchar(50) NULL
    ,collocazioneTipo nvarchar(50) NULL
    ,ospedaleReparto nvarchar(255) NULL
    );
    -- collocazioni --

    -- stati clinici --
    CREATE TABLE #xmlStatiClinici
    (
    patientID int NULL
    ,statoClinicoId int NULL
    ,dataStatoClinico date NULL
    ,terapiaInCorso int NULL
    ,terapia nvarchar(1000) NULL
    ,Intubato int NULL
    ,patientID_reg nvarchar(50) NULL
    ,tipoStatoClinico nvarchar(50) NULL
    );
    -- stati clinici --

    -- index on temp tables --
        CREATE INDEX ixTmp_patient_patientId ON #xmlPazienti (patientId);
        CREATE INDEX ixTmp_patient_patientID_reg ON #xmlPazienti (patientID_reg);
        CREATE INDEX ixTmp_patient_codRegione ON #xmlPazienti (codRegione) INCLUDE (patientId);
        CREATE INDEX ixTmp_patient_LaboratorioAnalisiId ON #xmlPazienti (LaboratorioAnalisiId);
        CREATE INDEX ixTmp_ricovero_patientId ON #xmlCollocazioni (patientId);
        CREATE INDEX ixTmp_ricovero_patientID_reg ON #xmlCollocazioni (patientID_reg);
        CREATE INDEX ixTmp_ricovero_collocazioneID ON #xmlCollocazioni (collocazioneID);
        CREATE INDEX ixTmp_ricovero_idOspedale ON #xmlCollocazioni (idOspedale);
        CREATE INDEX ixTmp_ricovero_codReparto ON #xmlCollocazioni (codReparto);
        CREATE INDEX ixTmp_monitoring_patientId ON #xmlStatiClinici (patientId);
        CREATE INDEX ixTmp_monitoring_patientID_reg ON #xmlStatiClinici (patientID_reg);
        CREATE INDEX ixTmp_monitoring_statoClinicoId ON #xmlStatiClinici (statoClinicoId);
    -- index on temp tables --


DECLARE @StartTimeInsertPazienti datetime = getdate()
DECLARE @fId INT = 187
DECLARE @XML AS XML
SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLbulkLoad WHERE Id = @fId
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://covid-19.iss.it/XMLSchema/0.1/')
    -- pazienti --
    INSERT INTO #xmlPazienti WITH (TABLOCK) ([patientID_reg],[codiceFiscale],[cognome],[nome],[dataNascita],[sesso],[nazionalita],[domicilioInd],[domicilioCap],[domicilioCom],[domicilioProv],[residenzaInd],[residenzaCap],[residenzaCom],[residenzaProv],[luogoEsp],[luogoEspCom],[operatoreSanitario],[casoIsolato],[casoCollegato],[CodiceTampone],[dataPrelievo],[LaboratorioAnalisiId],[sequenzaGenoma],[sequenzaInviata],[DataInizioSintomi],[codRegione],[PatologieCroniche],[TumoriAttivi],[DiabeteMellito],[MalattieCardiovascolari],[HIV],[MalattieRespiratorieCroniche],[MalattieRenali],[AltreMalattieMetaboliche],[ObesitàBMI30e40],[ObesitàBMIoltre40],[MalattieEpatiche],[MalattieCronicheNeurologiche],[AltrePatologie],[AltrePatologieDescrizione],[Note])
    SELECT   ISNULL(paz.value('(codiceRegionalePaziente/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(50)'),NULL) AS [patientID_reg]  
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(codiceFiscale/text())[1]', 'varchar(16)'),NULL) AS [codiceFiscale]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(cognome/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)'),NULL) AS [cognome]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(nome/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)'),NULL) AS [nome]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(dataNascita/text())[1]', 'datetime'),NULL) AS [dataNascita]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(sesso/text())[1]', 'char(1)'),NULL) AS [sesso]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(nazionalita/text())[1]', 'smallint'),NULL) AS [nazionalita]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(domicilioIndirizzo/text())[1]', 'varchar(255)'),NULL) AS [domicilioInd]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(domicilioCap/text())[1]', 'varchar(10)'),NULL) AS [domicilioCap]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(domicilioComune/text())[1]', 'varchar(255)'),NULL) AS [domicilioCom]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(domicilioProvincia/text())[1]', 'varchar(255)'),NULL) AS [domicilioProv]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(residenzaIndirizzo/text())[1]', 'varchar(255)'),NULL) AS [residenzaInd]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(residenzaCap/text())[1]', 'varchar(10)'),NULL) AS [residenzaCap]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(residenzaComune/text())[1]', 'varchar(255)'),NULL) AS [residenzaCom]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(residenzaProvincia/text())[1]', 'varchar(255)'),NULL) AS [residenzaProv]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(luogoEsposizione/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),NULL) AS [luogoEsp]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(luogoEsposizioneComune/text())[1]', 'varchar(255)'),NULL) AS [luogoEspCom]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(operatoreSanitario/text())[1]', 'tinyint'),NULL) AS [operatoreSanitario]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(casoIsolato/text())[1]', 'tinyint'),NULL) AS [casoIsolato]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(casoCollegato/text())[1]', 'varchar(500)'),NULL) AS [casoCollegato]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(codiceTampone/text())[1]', 'varchar(255)'),NULL) AS [CodiceTampone]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(dataPrelievo/text())[1]', 'date'),NULL) AS [dataPrelievo]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(codLaboratorioAnalisi/text())[1]', 'smallint'),NULL) AS [LaboratorioAnalisiId]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(sequenzaGenoma/text())[1]', 'tinyint'),NULL) AS [sequenzaGenoma]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(sequenzaInviata/text())[1]', 'tinyint'),NULL) AS [sequenzaInviata]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(dataInizioSintomi/text())[1]', 'date'),NULL) AS [dataInizioSintomi]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(codRegione/text())[1]', 'smallint'),'') AS [codRegione]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(patologieCroniche/text())[1]', 'tinyint'),NULL) AS [patologieCroniche]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(tumoriAttivi/text())[1]', 'tinyint'),NULL) AS [tumoriAttivi]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(diabeteMellito/text())[1]', 'tinyint'),NULL) AS [diabeteMellito]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(malattieCardiovascolari/text())[1]', 'tinyint'),NULL) AS [malattieCardiovascolari]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(hiv/text())[1]', 'tinyint'),NULL) AS [hiv]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(malattieRespiratorieCroniche/text())[1]', 'tinyint'),NULL) AS [malattieRespiratorieCroniche]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(malattieRenali/text())[1]', 'tinyint'),NULL) AS [malattieRenali]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(altreMalattieMetaboliche/text())[1]', 'tinyint'),NULL) AS [altreMalattieMetaboliche]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(obesitaBmi30e40/text())[1]', 'tinyint'),NULL) AS [ObesitàBMI30e40]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(obesitaBmiOltre40/text())[1]', 'tinyint'),NULL) AS [ObesitàBMIoltre40]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(malattieEpatiche/text())[1]', 'tinyint'),NULL) AS [malattieEpatiche]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(malattieCronicheNeurologiche/text())[1]', 'tinyint'),NULL) AS [malattieCronicheNeurologiche]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(altrePatologie/text())[1]', 'tinyint'),NULL) AS [altrePatologie]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(altrePatologieDescrizione/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),NULL) AS [altrePatologieDescrizione]
            ,ISNULL(paz.value('(note/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)'),NULL) AS [note]
    FROM  
         @XML.nodes('covid-19/pazienti/paziente') AS A(paz)
         --OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)
         --OPTION (RECOMPILE)
    -- pazienti --
DECLARE @EndTimeInsertPazienti datetime = getdate()
SELECT DATEDIFF (SS ,@StartTimeInsertPazienti,@EndTimeInsertPazienti) AS PazientiInsertDuration

DECLARE @StartTimeInsertCollocazioni datetime = getdate()
    -- collocazioni --
    --SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLbulkLoadDEV WHERE Id = @fID
    --;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://covid-19.iss.it/XMLSchema/0.1/')
    INSERT INTO #xmlCollocazioni WITH (TABLOCK) (patientID_reg, dataRicovero, collocazioneTipo, idOspedale, ospedaleReparto)
    SELECT  COALESCE(paz.value('(codiceRegionalePaziente/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(50)'),NULL) AS [patientID_reg]      
            ,COALESCE(coll.value('(dataCollocazione/text())[1]', 'date'),NULL) AS [dataRicovero]
            ,COALESCE(coll.value('(collocazioneTipo/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(50)'),NULL) AS [collocazioneTipo]
            ,COALESCE(coll.value('(ospedaleNSIS/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)'),NULL) AS [idOspedale]
            ,COALESCE(coll.value('(ospedaleReparto/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)'),NULL) AS [ospedaleReparto]
    FROM  
         @XML.nodes('covid-19/pazienti/paziente') AS A(paz) 
     OUTER APPLY 
         paz.nodes('collocazioni/collocazione') B(coll)
         --OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)
         --OPTION (RECOMPILE)
    -- collocazioni --
DECLARE @EndTimeInsertCollocazioni datetime = getdate()
SELECT DATEDIFF (SS ,@StartTimeInsertCollocazioni,@EndTimeInsertCollocazioni) AS CollocazioniInsertDuration

DECLARE @StarTimeInsertStatiClinici datetime = getdate()

    -- stati clinici --
    --SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLbulkLoadDEV WHERE Id = @fID
    --;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://covid-19.iss.it/XMLSchema/0.1/')
    INSERT INTO #xmlStatiClinici WITH (TABLOCK) (patientID_reg, tipoStatoClinico, dataStatoClinico, terapiaInCorso, terapia, intubato)
    SELECT   ISNULL(paz.value('(codiceRegionalePaziente/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(50)'),NULL) AS [patientID_reg]      
            ,ISNULL(sc.value('(tipoStatoClinico/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(50)'),NULL) AS [tipoStatoClinico]
            ,ISNULL(sc.value('(dataStatoClinico/text())[1]', 'date'),NULL) AS [dataStatoClinico]
            ,ISNULL(sc.value('(terapiaInCorso/text())[1]', 'int'),0) AS [terapiaInCorso]
            ,ISNULL(sc.value('(terapiaDescrizione/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(1000)'),NULL) AS [terapia]
            ,ISNULL(sc.value('(intubato/text())[1]', 'int'),NULL) AS [intubato]
    FROM  
         @XML.nodes('covid-19/pazienti/paziente') AS A(paz) 
     OUTER APPLY 
         paz.nodes('statiClinici/statoClinico') C(sc)
        --OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)
        --OPTION (RECOMPILE)
    -- stati clinici --
DECLARE @EndTimeInsertStatiClinici datetime = getdate()
SELECT DATEDIFF (SS ,@StarTimeInsertStatiClinici,@EndTimeInsertStatiClinici) AS StatiCliniciInsertDuration
    --
    --select * from XMLbulkLoad

DECLARE @EndTimeInsert datetime = getdate()
SELECT DATEDIFF (SS ,@StartTimeInsertPazienti,@EndTimeInsertStatiClinici) AS TotalInsertDuration

    -- DROP temp tables
    if object_id('tempdb..#xmlPazienti') is not null DROP TABLE #xmlPazienti;
    if object_id('tempdb..#xmlCollocazioni') is not null DROP TABLE #xmlCollocazioni;
    if object_id('tempdb..#xmlStatiClinici') is not null DROP TABLE #xmlStatiClinici;
```

The problem is that when there are a few hundred (or fewer)  elements in the XML, the query performs just fine. However, when there are 25,000  elements, it takes 50 seconds to finish returning the rows in SSMS and I could have 50-100,000  elements.

Is there a more efficient way to transform the XML document into the tabular dataset (in SQL)?

Comment: To be pedantic, I suspect it's quadratic rather than exponential. It makes a difference because (a) quadratic isn't nearly as bad, and (b) knowing the difference can help to isolate the cause. Sadly though I don't understand the database technology you're using well enough to be able to pinpoint the cause.

Comment: (1) You can try to shred XML by accessing it directly from the XMLbulkLoad table without using the @XML variable. (2) It is not clear why you are using ISNULL() function for each data element. They will have NULL values on there own depending on the source XML..

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I tried to shred XML directly from the XMLbulkLoad table: no improvement. Then I added an xml index on table and the query takes only 12 seconds BUT.. bulk load on table goes from 4 seconds to 35 seconds!!! so the whole process is worse. any suggestion?

Comment: The most expensive action with XML is very often the initial parsing. Is the column `XMLData FROM XMLbulkLoad` natively XML typed`? it might help to read the whole lot in one staging table and fill your target tables from there with `SELECT ... GROUP BY` statements.

Comment: @Shnugo yes, XMLData column is natively XM typed. I don't understand when you said "it might help to read the whole lot in one staging table and fill your target tables from there with SELECT ... GROUP BY` statements": what you mean? Can you provide a short example please?

Answer (score 0):

One general hint might be: create your indexes as the final step. Especially with a lot of rows this will slow down any data manipulation (in this case your insert statements);

As pointed in my comment you might walk the *staging route*.

First I create a *mockup table* to simulate your issue

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(YourXML XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
(N'<covid-19 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://covid-19.iss.it/XMLSchema/0.1/">
    <pazienti>
        <paziente>
            <codiceRegionalePaziente>0123456789</codiceRegionalePaziente>
            <codiceFiscale/>
            <nome>nomeBulk01</nome>
            <cognome>cognomeBulk01</cognome>
            <!-- shortened -->
            <collocazioni>
                <collocazione>
                    <dataCollocazione>2020-03-01</dataCollocazione>
                    <!-- shortened -->
                </collocazione>
            </collocazioni>
            <statiClinici>
                <statoClinico>
                    <tipoStatoClinico>Asintomatico</tipoStatoClinico>
                    <!-- shortened -->
                </statoClinico>
                <statoClinico>
                    <tipoStatoClinico>Lieve</tipoStatoClinico>
                    <!-- shortened -->
                </statoClinico>
                <statoClinico>
                    <tipoStatoClinico>Critico</tipoStatoClinico>
                    <!-- shortened -->
                </statoClinico>
            </statiClinici>
        </paziente>
        <paziente>
            <codiceRegionalePaziente>AABB1234567890</codiceRegionalePaziente>
            <codiceFiscale>AAABBB00C11D222E</codiceFiscale>
            <nome>nomeBulk02</nome>
            <cognome>cognomeBulk02</cognome>
            <!-- shortened -->
            <collocazioni>
                <collocazione>
                    <dataCollocazione>2020-03-01</dataCollocazione>
                    <!-- shortened -->
                </collocazione>
                <collocazione>
                    <dataCollocazione>2020-03-05</dataCollocazione>
                    <!-- shortened -->
                </collocazione>
            </collocazioni>
            <statiClinici>
                <statoClinico>
                    <tipoStatoClinico>Pauci-sintomatico</tipoStatoClinico>
                    <!-- shortened -->
                </statoClinico>
                <statoClinico>
                    <tipoStatoClinico>Severo</tipoStatoClinico>
                    <!-- shortened -->
                </statoClinico>
            </statiClinici>
        </paziente>
        <paziente>
            <codiceRegionalePaziente>9999999</codiceRegionalePaziente>
            <codiceFiscale/>
            <nome>nomeBulk03</nome>
            <cognome>cognomeBulk03</cognome>
            <!-- shortened -->
            <collocazioni>
            </collocazioni>
            <statiClinici>
            </statiClinici>
        </paziente>
    </pazienti>
</covid-19>');
```

--The query

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://covid-19.iss.it/XMLSchema/0.1/')
SELECT   paz.value('(codiceRegionalePaziente/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS [patientID_reg]  
        ,paz.value('(codiceFiscale/text())[1]', 'varchar(16)') AS [codiceFiscale]
        ,paz.value('(cognome/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') AS [cognome]
        ,paz.value('(nome/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') AS [nome]
        --shortended

        ,coll.value('(dataCollocazione/text())[1]', 'date') AS [dataRicovero]
        --shortended

        ,sc.value('(tipoStatoClinico/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS [tipoStatoClinico]
        --shortended

 --Define a target staging table simply automatically
 INTO #StagingTable

 FROM @tbl t
 CROSS APPLY t.YourXML.nodes('covid-19/pazienti/paziente') AS A(paz)
 OUTER APPLY 
     paz.nodes('collocazioni/collocazione') B(coll)

 OUTER APPLY 
     paz.nodes('statiClinici/statoClinico') C(sc);
```

--now all your data is shifted into one big table

```
SELECT * FROM #StagingTable
```

--use something like this to get the patient data

```
SELECT patientID_reg,codiceFiscale,cognome,nome /*all patient related columns*/ 
FROM #StagingTable 
GROUP BY patientID_reg,codiceFiscale,cognome,nome /*all patient related columns*/;
```

--This will your related data.

```
SELECT patientID_reg,dataRicovero /*all collocazioni related data*/ 
FROM #StagingTable 
GROUP BY patientID_reg,dataRicovero /*all collocazioni related data*/

SELECT patientID_reg,tipoStatoClinico /*all stati clinici related data*/ 
FROM #StagingTable 
GROUP BY patientID_reg,tipoStatoClinico /*all stati clinici related data*/
```

You can perform any cleaning, or check of business logic, against the staged data. It might be a good idea to check for existing `patientID_reg` values in your target table...
Then shift the cleaned data into your final target tables.

### UPDATE

Attention: If your XML might carry the same `patientID_reg` value for different elements you will have to add a `ROW_NUMBER()`

In this case you might use something along this:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://covid-19.iss.it/XMLSchema/0.1/')
,ReadPatientDataWithRowNumber AS
(
    SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS PatientNumber
            ,paz.value('(codiceRegionalePaziente/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS [patientID_reg]  
            ,paz.value('(codiceFiscale/text())[1]', 'varchar(16)') AS [codiceFiscale]
            ,paz.value('(cognome/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') AS [cognome]
            ,paz.value('(nome/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') AS [nome]
            --shortended
            ,paz.query('collocazioni/collocazione') AS CollocazioneXml
            ,paz.query('statiClinici/statoClinico') AS StatoClinicoXml
     FROM @tbl t
     CROSS APPLY t.YourXML.nodes('covid-19/pazienti/paziente') AS A(paz)
)
,AddTheRest AS
(
    SELECT pd.*

    ,coll.value('(dataCollocazione/text())[1]', 'date') AS [dataRicovero]
    --shortended

    ,sc.value('(tipoStatoClinico/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS [tipoStatoClinico]
    --shortended

    FROM ReadPatientDataWithRowNumber pd
     OUTER APPLY 
         pd.CollocazioneXml.nodes('collocazioni/collocazione') B(coll)

     OUTER APPLY 
         pd.StatoClinicoXml.nodes('statiClinici/statoClinico') C(sc)
)   
SELECT * 
INTO #StagingTable
FROM AddTheRest


SELECT PatientNumber,patientID_reg,codiceFiscale,cognome,nome /*all patient related columns*/ 
FROM #StagingTable 
GROUP BY PatientNumber,patientID_reg,codiceFiscale,cognome,nome /*all patient related columns*/;

SELECT PatientNumber,patientID_reg,dataRicovero /*all collocazioni related data*/ 
FROM #StagingTable 
GROUP BY PatientNumber,patientID_reg,dataRicovero /*all collocazioni related data*/

SELECT PatientNumber,patientID_reg,tipoStatoClinico /*all stati clinici related data*/ 
FROM #StagingTable 
GROUP BY PatientNumber,patientID_reg,tipoStatoClinico /*all stati clinici related data*/
```

### UPDATE 2

Please check this:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://covid-19.iss.it/XMLSchema/0.1/')
,ReadPatientDataWithRowNumber AS
(
    SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS PatientNumber
            ,paz.value('(codiceRegionalePaziente/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS [patientID_reg]  
            ,paz.value('(codiceFiscale/text())[1]', 'varchar(16)') AS [codiceFiscale]
            ,paz.value('(cognome/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') AS [cognome]
            ,paz.value('(nome/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') AS [nome]
            --shortended
            ,paz.query('collocazioni/collocazione') AS CollocazioneXml
            ,paz.query('statiClinici/statoClinico') AS StatoClinicoXml
     FROM @tbl t
     CROSS APPLY t.YourXML.nodes('covid-19/pazienti/paziente') AS A(paz)
)
SELECT * 
INTO #StagingTable
FROM ReadPatientDataWithRowNumber

SELECT * FROM #StagingTable;
```

Comment: thank you, now I understand your approach, it was also my first tentative using one big staging table. I don't think it might improve response time because the insert statement is the same but now there is a cross join so the insert is more more big.. forget the related table for a moment, just think to patient table: I absolutely need to drop the insert time

Comment: @mtallon Well, this might be clear for you, but not for me...  Querying the XML just once should be faster... And I cannot see the CROSS JOIN... You might use the code in my UPDATE section without the CTE `AddTheRest`. This would insert exactly one row per `<paziente>` into the `#StagingTable`, while related side data remains as XML fragments. Should be easy to proceed from there...

Comment: you have cartesian product of nr. patient x nr. collocazioni x nr. staticlinici so for example if I add another element collocazione it will result in 11 record in stagingtable instead of 3. anyway  I tried the code in your UPDATE, I get 3 patient inserted in #StagingTable and 3 record with null dataRicovero and 3 record with null tipoStatoClinico... sorry if I don't understand..

Comment: @malton Check the section UPDATE 2. At least with the given sample this shows up with values...

Comment: sorry for my late response. I give a try to your solution UPDATE 2: if I add an xml index on table your query takes only 8 seconds (my query takes 12 seconds); but the initial bulk insert take more time with index (35 seconds - while only 4 without index). If I try your UPDATE 2 on table without index, my query takes 35 seconds while yours is still running after 6 minutes...

Comment: @mtallon Well, you are the only one to answer this, I'm afraid... XML indixes can help a lot but only in very special situations. [I placed a question my self a while ago](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/130969/70663) It might even slow down your query... The only hint I have for you: Try to measure the times separately (loading, parsing, shredding, inserting) to find the most promising screw to adjust...